# How to write a query with join, update and order by?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables: tblRider and tbl_SCORE. tblRider has all the information about all the riders (competitors) and in tbl_SCORE are all the riders's scores saved.
I want to update a column HalfPipeFinal in tblRider. Standard this column is set on 0, but I want to set it on 1 for the riders with the 20 best scores. (so only the 20 best riders can participate in the final and those who do have a 1 in column HalfPipeRider)

This is my query:

```
UPDATE tblRider
JOIN tbl_SCORE ON tblRider.riderID = tbl_SCORE.riderID
SET tblRider.HalfPipeFinal = 1
WHERE `gameID` =35
ORDER BY `score` DESC
limit 20;**
```

If I run this query I get this error: "Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY"
So I went looking and apparently you can't use update and order by in a join. So I am looking for an other way to write this query without a order by in it, but I can't find it.

All help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you run this query without "order by".. ?? what did the error msg displayed then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In SQL you can't have an `ORDER BY` as part of the `UPDATE` itself. But you can make the filter a subquery, give it an alias and join it...

```
UPDATE tblRider r
JOIN 
(
    SELECT riderID 
    FROM tbl_SCORE
    WHERE gameID = 35
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 20 
) s
ON r.riderID = s.riderID
SET r.HalfPipeFinal = 1;
```

Comment: This only works if the WHERE condition only involves the second table :(

Comment: Is it specified anywhere that the order will hold from the subquery to the outer update?

Comment: @shmosel yes, in the `ON` clause. The subquery `s` *should* only return the 20 highest scoring riders in game 35.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head and without having a SQL session open to test this you could try...

```
UPDATE tblRider  
SET HalfPipeFinal = 1 
WHERE riderID 
IN 
(
  SELECT s.riderID 
  FROM tbl_SCORE
  ORDER BY s.score 
  DESC limit 20
)
```

Though `IN (subselect)` can have unpleasant performance penalties.